Should I delete the tag, "puzzle"?
I have (accidentally) created a tag, puzzle. Should I delete this tag?

Note that unused tags (not associated with a question) are removed periodically and automatically.

OK, I will remove it from the question..

Sure. There is not much reason to keep it around.
